# React Hook Form: How to Manage Separate Control for Each Card in a Dynamic Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm creating a layout similar to [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/20021003-Formy-Form-Builder-Platform) where you have cards down the center and a sidebar which populates with the card settings when one is clicked on.

The issue I'm having is that when I select a card, the settings don't update properly and will retain the previous card's settings when you click on another card.

I've tried using a generic register inside the sidepane but this doesn't work as it will re-register a new item each time the sidebar open, closes or changes.

I've also tried using the useController but it has similar functionality to the generic registering.

See the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-settings-render-cgspqm?file=/src/App.js) for a re-creation of the problem.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, useController } from "react-hook-form";

// Registering doesn't woek as the checked will be re registered each time we focus a question
// function FocusCard({ question, index, register }) {
//   return (
//     <div>
//       <div>{`Question: ${question.question}`}</div>
//       <input
//         type="checkbox"
//         {...register(`survey.questions.${index}.checked`)}
//       />
//     </div>
//   );
// }

// useController
function FocusCard({ question, index, control }) {
  const { field } = useController({
    name: `survey.questions.${index}.checked`,
    control
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`Question: ${question.question}`}</div>
      <label>Check me</label>
      <input type="checkbox" {...field} />
    </div>
  );
}

function QuestionCard({ question, index, setFocus }) {
  return (
    <div className="question" onClick={(e) => setFocus(e, index)}>
      {question.question}
    </div>
  );
}

//app.js
export default function App() {
  const [selectedIndex, setIndex] = useState(null);
  const { register, handleSubmit, control, getValues, setValue } = useForm();

  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray({
    control: control,
    name: "survey.questions"
  });

  const handleSave = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const handleAddQuestion = (e) => {
    if (getValues("survey.question") !== "") {
      append({ question: getValues("survey.question") });
      setValue("survey.question", "");
    }
  };

  const handleFocus = (e, index) => {
    if (index === selectedIndex) {
      setIndex(null);
    } else {
      setIndex(index);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSave)}>
        <h2>Focused Question</h2>
        {selectedIndex !== null && (
          // <FocusCard
          //   index={selectedIndex}
          //   register={register}
          //   question={fields[selectedIndex]}
          // />
          <FocusCard
            index={selectedIndex}
            control={control}
            question={fields[selectedIndex]}
          />
        )}
        <h2>All Questions</h2>
        {fields &&
          fields.map((q, i) => (
            <QuestionCard
              key={q.id}
              question={q}
              index={i}
              setFocus={handleFocus}
            />
          ))}
        <br />
        <input type="text" {...register("survey.question")} />
        <button type="button" onClick={handleAddQuestion}>
          Add Question
        </button>
        <button type="Button" onClick={() => setIndex(null)}>Unfocus</button>
        <button type="submit">Print Data to Console</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this point **"The issue I'm having is that when I select a card, the settings don't update properly and will retain the previous card's settings when you click on another card."** Do you mean something like say I checked the checkbox of one card and I clicked on another card then the checkbox for that card is also being checked?

Comment: Exactly, so if you select an item and check the checkbox it will be checked. Then if you add another item and select it, it’s checkbox will default to checked . If you then deselect all and select the same item again then it’s checkbox will be unchecked.

Comment: Does **[this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/form-settings-render-forked-z2w68n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)** help?

Comment: Not quite, If you create a question say 'q1' and another 'q2', then focus q1 and check the checkbox. If you then focus q2, the checkbox changes to unchecked as expected but if you then focus q1 again, the checkbox remains unchecked when it should go back to checked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue which I was able to figure out is somehow the value for `checked` attribute is not properly updated(maybe `question` object needs to be maintained with init values) because of this the checkbox remains unchecked when it should go back to checked.

I have used the **[defaultValue](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller)** property of `useController` to make the adjustments to work as per your expectation.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, useController } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";

// useController
function FocusCard({ question, index, control }) {
  const { field } = useController({
    name: `survey.questions.${index}.checked`,
    control,
    defaultValue: question.checked || false // Added this line
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`Question: ${question.question}`}</div>
      <label>Check me</label>
      {/* Updated this to explicitly assign the checked value*/}
      <input type="checkbox" {...field} checked={field.value} />
    </div>
  );
}

function QuestionCard({ question, index, setFocus }) {
  return (
    <div className="question" onClick={(e) => setFocus(e, index)}>
      {question.question}
    </div>
  );
}

//app.js
export default function App() {
  const [selectedIndex, setIndex] = useState(null);
  const { register, handleSubmit, control, getValues, setValue } = useForm();

  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray({
    control: control,
    name: "survey.questions"
  });

  const handleSave = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const handleAddQuestion = (e) => {
    if (getValues("survey.question") !== "") {
      append({ question: getValues("survey.question") });
      setValue("survey.question", "");
    }
  };

  const handleFocus = (e, index) => {
    if (index === selectedIndex) {
      setIndex(null);
    } else {
      setIndex(index);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSave)}>
        <h2>Focused Question</h2>
        {selectedIndex !== null && (
          <FocusCard
            key={selectedIndex} // Added this line
            index={selectedIndex}
            control={control}
            question={fields[selectedIndex]}
          />
        )}
        <h2>All Questions</h2>
        {fields &&
          fields.map((q, i) => (
            <QuestionCard
              key={q.id}
              question={q}
              index={i}
              setFocus={handleFocus}
            />
          ))}
        <br />
        <input type="text" {...register("survey.question")} />
        <button type="button" onClick={handleAddQuestion}>
          Add Question
        </button>
        <button type="submit">Print Data to Console</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**[APPLICATION DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-settings-render-forked-y7w4dj?file=/src/App.js)**